# How do I get two side by side html input fields to look combined with a middle separator that is less than the input field heights?

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve something like below[image]

How do I style the html and css?

Comment: (0) By writing some code that aims to achieve it, (1) examining the difference between the desired output and the actual one, before (2) refining your approach. - You appear still to be stuck at #0,it would probably help if you expended at least _some_ effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello you can enclose the two input fields in a div then add margins inside. Here's a summary of what I did;

1. put input fields inside a div
2. remove borders from the input fields
3. add margin on top & bottom of the input fields (this would be the spacing on top and bottom of the separator)
4. add a border on the right of the first input field

Do run the snippet below, thanks.

```js
$(".input-group-wrapper input").on("focus", function() {
  $(this).parent().addClass("focus");
});

$(".input-group-wrapper input").on("focusout", function() {
  $(this).parent().removeClass("focus");
});
```

```css
.input-group-wrapper {
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 0.2s;
  width: 100%;
}

.input-group-wrapper>.first,
.input-group-wrapper>.second {
  border: none;
  line-height: 30px;
  display: inline;
  margin: 6px 0px 6px 0px;
  padding: 0px 8px 0px 8px;
}

.input-group-wrapper>.first {
  width: 60%;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.input-group-wrapper>.second {
  width: 30%;
}

.input-group-wrapper>.first:focus,
.input-group-wrapper>.first:active,
.input-group-wrapper>.second:focus,
.input-group-wrapper>.second:active {
  outline: none;
}

.focus {
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 100, 200, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<div class='input-group-wrapper'>
  <input class='first' placeholder='e.g. Read every day p3 @goals #learning' />
  <input class='second' value='Aug 4 2018' />
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this look, you'll want to use a margin on one of them.
I have my code and a Code Pen linked below:

```css
 .modified{
            height: 30px;
            border-radius: 2px;
            border: 1px solid lightgray;
            box-shadow: none;
            padding: 3px 6px;
        }
        .modified.right{
            margin-left: -10px;
            width: 125px;/* Alternatively use % or vw */
        }

        .modified.right::placeholder{
            color: black;
        }
```

```html
<input type="text" class="modified" placeholder="Just Test Me"/>
     <input type="text" class="modified right" placeholder="I Am Testing" />
```

[Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/spencerkmedia/pen/XxJxNo)

I hope this helps!